# where is https and webdav timeout settings

Tags: iis, timeout, webdav

I have IIS on a WIN 10 PC where I have connected an external 12 TB HDD to the USB port.
I have linked the drive correctly in IIS to WEBDAV Service. It works locally with private IP on port 4444.

But when I use my domain name and port outside, then it takes too long to list the DIRs either in CAROTDAV or in Chrome Browser. A timeout error comes up. ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
on port 4433 another Ubuntu Webdav service with a small HDD works fine also from outside.

Where in IIS can I set the TIMEOUT Time, so that it will work also with my big HDD?
THANKS.

Comment: maybe this helps? stackoverflow.com/a/55775418/4560093 try disabling directory listing to see if thats the problem causing the timeout or not...

Comment: Are you trying to connect via HTTPS or HTTP? WebDav only supports https.

Comment: @AndiAna thanks it works now.